# ALTER TABLE error when adding new column

Tags: mysql, alter-table

```
    ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mycolumn INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
```

When doing this I get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(0)' at line 2

Any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  syntax for `DEFAULT` clause only accept a *value* not an *expression* (even constant). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html:

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.

---

Concretely, you have to remove the parenthesis:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mycolumn INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mycolumn INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from the default value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mycolumn INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```